# Double header in longtable

Tags: tables, lyx, longtable, r

I'm trying to make a longtable and use some R tools for generating them. The problem is that when a long table has more than one columns, it creates double headers, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20552459/excessive-elements-in-latex-longtable-output-when-more-than-one-row-is-used-in-h. I use LyX to generate the output.

This is one-column code:

```
\begin{document}

\setlongtables


\begin{longtable}{r}\caption{Title} \tabularnewline
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{X1.10}\tabularnewline
\hline
\endfirsthead\caption[]{\em (continued)} \tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{X1.10}\tabularnewline
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
\label{data.frame}
$ 1$\tabularnewline
$ 2$\tabularnewline
$ 3$\tabularnewline
$ 4$\tabularnewline
$ 5$\tabularnewline
$ 6$\tabularnewline
$ 7$\tabularnewline
$ 8$\tabularnewline
$ 9$\tabularnewline
$10$\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

And this is a two-column table:

```
\begin{document}

\setlongtables


\begin{longtable}{rr}\caption{Title} \tabularnewline
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{X1.10}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{X10.1}\tabularnewline
\hline
\endfirsthead\caption[]{\em (continued)} \tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{X1.10}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{X10.1}\tabularnewline
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
\label{data.frame}
$ 1$&$10$\tabularnewline
$ 2$&$ 9$\tabularnewline
$ 3$&$ 8$\tabularnewline
$ 4$&$ 7$\tabularnewline
$ 5$&$ 6$\tabularnewline
$ 6$&$ 5$\tabularnewline
$ 7$&$ 4$\tabularnewline
$ 8$&$ 3$\tabularnewline
$ 9$&$ 2$\tabularnewline
$10$&$ 1$\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

What's wrong with the latter one? Judging from the code, they are identical.

**UPDATE**

That was LyX: when my .tex file was imported in LyX, it created additional code (the header), so that further processing went wrong.

Comment: Should the two posts be merged?

Answer (score 3):

Please always post *complete* documents that show the problem. I had to guess to complete your fragment but I only get one heading, so presumably the problem is in the code you didn't show.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\setlongtables


\begin{longtable}{rr}\caption{Title} \tabularnewline
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{X1.10}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{X10.1}\tabularnewline
\hline
\endfirsthead\caption[]{\em (continued)} \tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{X1.10}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{X10.1}\tabularnewline
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
\label{data.frame}
$ 1$&$10$\tabularnewline
$ 2$&$ 9$\tabularnewline
$ 3$&$ 8$\tabularnewline
$ 4$&$ 7$\tabularnewline
$ 5$&$ 6$\tabularnewline
$ 6$&$ 5$\tabularnewline
$ 7$&$ 4$\tabularnewline
$ 8$&$ 3$\tabularnewline
$ 9$&$ 2$\tabularnewline
$10$&$ 1$\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, David. I actually found the mistake. It was my file processing via LyX that added another row. Thanks to you I've checked it properly.

Comment: @Anton do you want to close the question if it was a simple error , or if there is some general advice worth giving you could give a self answer (better an answer than adding it to the question)

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred because I did conversion from .tex to .lyx before rendering a PDF file. At this stage, LyX tried to convert `longtable` (not a part of its native capacities) into a double simple table and added the double header.